# How to make "SBAwayController * controller = [objc_getClass("SBAwayController") sharedAwayController]" working？

Tags: frameworks, private

I want to check whether the screen is locked with private api.

And I get some code from google:

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>  
#import <SpringBoard/SBAwayController.h>

Class clsAway = objc_allocateClassPair(clsAlert, "SBAwayController", 0);
objc_registerClassPair(clsAway);

Class clsAwayController = objc_getClass("SBAwayController");
SBAwayController * controller = [clsAwayController sharedAwayController];

if ([controller isLocked]){
    NSLog(@"double check Home ,now YES Lock");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"double check Home ,now NO Lock");
}
```

To make these code to work, I download the private headers from kennytm's github and import SpringBoard.h and SBAwayController.h
Compile ok and run it on my iPhone 4S, it seems that I can get a non-nil pointer with objc_getClass("SBAwayController");
But the program crashed at line:

```
SBAwayController * controller = [clsAwayController sharedAwayController];
```

with an error: '+[SBAwayController sharedAwayController]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1456c0'

Any other works do I need to make these code to work?
I know that the usage of private api can cause the rejection from Apple, but I just want to know how to make it work. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

SBAwayController WAS NOT REMOVED IN iOS 5. How can you expect to use a SpringBoard method from another process? SpringBoard is NOT a framework. It's an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SBAwayController was removed in the iOS 5. I checked SpringBoard and it has only reminiscences of this class.

Comment: What tool did you use to decompile the executable? class-dump? I dumped an iOS7 SpringBoard executable and couldn't find this header either.

Comment: I used Hopper Disassembler. I doesn't dump .h files, but rather I can see disassembled code.

Answer (score 0):

Victor is wrong.  The class is still present in iOS 6

```
cy# c = SBAwayController.sharedAwayController;
@"<SBAwayController: 0x1c510580> <SBActivationContext: 0x1c50be50> activate:  deactivate: "

cy# printMethods(SBAwayController);
[{selector:@selector(hasEverBeenLocked),implementation:0x109c49},{selector:@selector(activateLostModeForRemoteLock:),implementation:0x116505},{selector:@selector(unlockWithSound:),implementation:0x110835},{selector:@selector(frontLocked:animate:automatically:),implementation:0x1120d5},{selector:@selector(cancelDimTimer),implementation:0x11291d},{selector:@selector(activeAwayPluginController),implementation:0x116885},{selector:@selector(shouldShowInCallUI),implementation:0x116111
...
```